# Getting listener in background fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, callback, onclicklistener

i have search a lot for the solution but didn't find, My case is I have **fragment1** which contain list, On-click of **fragment1** I am adding **fragment2** on the same activity, now **fragment2** is on top of **fragment1**. so I want listener/callback from **fragment2** to **fragment1**,means whatever i am doing on **fragment2** should reflect on **fragment1**. currently i achieve the scenario by using dialogfragment on top of **fragment1** with interface but i want to use fragment instead of dialogfragment.

Comment: need more info. What are u doing in your 2nd fragment ? What should change in your 1st fragment when you do something in 2nd fragment ?

Comment: @KarthicSrinivasan i have recyclerview in fragment1 and on click of that list item fragment2 will open which contain details view and one button. now onClick of that button that specific list item value need to be changed.so when user cancel fragment2 user will get changed values in list alos.

Comment: From where are you getting the data to populate your list ? Firebase or local SQLite ?

Comment: @KarthicSrinivasan from API response which is on the fragment1 , i m using retrofit.